# archlinux/i3wm: monitor recognized via xrandr but stays black

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xrandr

I have this weird issue with connecting an external monitor via usb-c to my arch linux machine where I run i3 as window manager.

My setup is a Lenovo Thinkvision T27hv-20 as docking station which I connect via usb-c (to also charge my machine) and a dell monitor daisy-chained to the thinkvision.

I can see the monitor connected via xrandr/DP, but xrandr --auto or xrandr --output DisplayPort-x --auto will not wake up the monitor. When I connect via hdmi cable and an adapter it works.

I can rule out cable issues - works fine on another machine (kali linux).

I am officially out of ideas - anyone experience the same issues?

uname -a:

`Linux mor3dr3ad 6.1.4-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 07 Jan 2023 15:10:07 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+
   1680x1050     60.03
   1280x1024     60.03
   1440x900      60.03
   1280x800      60.03
   1280x720      60.03
   1024x768      60.03
   800x600       60.03
   640x480       60.03
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.78
   1920x1200     59.88
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DisplayPort-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-6 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00
   1920x1200     59.88
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DisplayPort-7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

sudo dmesg | grep intel

```
[   31.798607] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   31.813810] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[   31.813820] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[   31.813999] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   31.814044] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   31.816435] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
[   31.816439] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-RENOIR-037
[   31.819450] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature enabled
[   31.819455] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: PCIE atomic ops is not supported
[   31.819478] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: MODE2 reset
[   31.819541] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 512M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F41FFFFFFF (512M used)
[   31.819543] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
[   31.819545] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267419648M 0x000000F800000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
[   31.819615] [drm] amdgpu: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[   31.819617] [drm] amdgpu: 15659M of GTT memory ready.
[   31.828831] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist
[   31.828836] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist
[   31.867029] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[   32.665312] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[   32.676395] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[   32.681418] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
[   32.713598] snd_hda_intel 0000:06:00.1: bound 0000:06:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[   32.987819] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
[   32.987900] amdgpu: sdma_bitmap: 3
[   33.012307] amdgpu: HMM registered 512MB device memory
[   33.012338] amdgpu: SRAT table not found
[   33.012338] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
[   33.013066] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x1636:0x1002]
[   33.013070] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:1636
[   33.013270] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 8, active_cu_number 7
[   33.013337] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[   33.013339] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[   33.013340] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[   33.013341] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[   33.013342] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[   33.013343] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[   33.013343] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[   33.013344] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[   33.013345] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[   33.013346] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[   33.013347] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[   33.013348] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[   33.013349] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[   33.013350] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[   33.013351] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[   33.023401] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.49.0 20150101 for 0000:06:00.0 on minor 0
[   33.028246] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   33.099031] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[   34.267943] WARNING: CPU: 13 PID: 158 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/core/dc_link.c:3533 update_mst_stream_alloc_table+0x150/0x160 [amdgpu]
[   34.268637] Modules linked in: cmac algif_hash bnep intel_rapl_msr btusb snd_acp3x_rn btrtl r8153_ecm btbcm snd_soc_dmic snd_acp3x_pdm_dma cdc_ether btintel snd_sof_amd_rembrandt usbnet btmtk snd_sof_amd_renoir mousedev snd_sof_amd_acp uvcvideo snd_sof_pci bluetooth iwlmvm videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_sof r8152 videobuf2_v4l2 joydev mii ecdh_generic videobuf2_common snd_sof_utils mac80211 snd_ctl_led intel_rapl_common amdgpu libarc4 snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_realtek think_lmi wmi_bmof firmware_attributes_class tps6598x snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress ac97_bus edac_mce_amd snd_hda_intel snd_pcm_dmaengine gpu_sched iwlwifi snd_intel_dspcfg snd_pci_ps snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_rpl_pci_acp6x drm_buddy vfat kvm_amd snd_hda_codec snd_acp_pci drm_ttm_helper fat snd_pci_acp6x snd_hda_core kvm ttm snd_pci_acp5x thinkpad_acpi cfg80211 snd_hwdep r8169 snd_rn_pci_acp3x ledtrig_audio drm_display_helper snd_pcm irqbypass realtek sp5100_tco snd_acp_config platform_profile
[   34.268872] RIP: 0010:update_mst_stream_alloc_table+0x150/0x160 [amdgpu]
[   34.269579]  dc_link_allocate_mst_payload+0x99/0x2a0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.270287]  core_link_enable_stream+0x7d0/0x980 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.270939]  ? optc1_set_drr+0x13a/0x1e0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.271609]  dce110_apply_ctx_to_hw+0x67b/0x720 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.272268]  dc_commit_state_no_check+0x38c/0xc90 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.272919]  dc_commit_state+0x96/0x110 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.273601]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x4a4/0x2ae0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.274268]  ? dcn21_fast_validate_bw+0x3c2/0x490 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.274930]  ? dcn21_validate_bandwidth_fp+0x115/0x6e0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.275602]  ? resource_build_scaling_params+0x908/0xeb0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.276263]  ? dc_fpu_end+0x97/0xb0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.276971]  ? dcn21_validate_bandwidth+0x47/0x60 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   34.277632]  ? dc_validate_global_state+0x310/0x3e0 [amdgpu e075343022af70307c8e70736313f8c62afdb58b]
[   38.607025] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* Step 2 of creating MST payload for 0000000045e93c42 failed: -5
[   66.138484] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* Step 2 of creating MST payload for 0000000045e93c42 failed: -5
[11351.377536] [drm:dc_link_allocate_mst_payload [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failure: pbn_per_slot==0 not allowed. Cannot continue, returning DC_UNSUPPORTED_VALUE.
[11352.575099] [drm:dc_link_allocate_mst_payload [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failure: pbn_per_slot==0 not allowed. Cannot continue, returning DC_UNSUPPORTED_VALUE.
[11363.726063] [drm:dc_link_allocate_mst_payload [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failure: pbn_per_slot==0 not allowed. Cannot continue, returning DC_UNSUPPORTED_VALUE.
[18411.665294] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: free PSP TMR buffer
[18412.614499] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[18412.627851] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[18412.633689] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
[18412.634029] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
[18412.635122] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
[18413.350692] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[18413.350695] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[18413.350697] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[18413.350698] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[18413.350699] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[18413.350700] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[18413.350701] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[18413.350703] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[18413.350704] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[18413.350705] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[18413.350707] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[18413.350708] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[18413.350709] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[18413.350710] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[18413.350712] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[18413.372379] [drm:dm_late_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DM_MST: Failed to start MST
[18413.373072] [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_late_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* late_init of IP block <dm> failed -5
[18413.373630] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_resume+0x0/0xf0 returns -5
[18413.373645] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by disabling Async flip.
I created this file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-noasyncflip.conf`
then added this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "modesetting"
    Option "PageFlip" "off"
EndSection
```

After a quick restart:

```shell
sudo systemctl restart display-manager.service
```

(or just reboot), this fixed my issue.

My issue was: I can see the cursor and for a few seconds after starting my system everything is fine. Sometimes when updating the resolution it also works but only for 1 monitor (have 2 external).